# Is there anyhow I can make pc camera concurrently accessible on windows?

Tags: concurrent-programming, video-camera

By default subsequent references to the camera will fail if it's already in use.

But is it possible to make the subsequent references **read-only**, but still can access the camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd377612.aspx), but to two different programs?  It can be done using a virtual camera driver.

Since you're on stackoverflow, I guess you're looking for a way to do this in code.  Try reading [this thread on the Microsoft discussion groups](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CCYQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsocial.msdn.microsoft.com%2FForums%2Fen-US%2Fwindowsdirectshowdevelopment%2Fthread%2F53e40f17-ae94-4050-8699-7a8761a87728&ei=Yq1gTM2RN4OglAe474T8BA&usg=AFQjCNEUUVhCPeXNntqU_m9ZHn_KGO7auw)

If you aren't a programmer, you should have asked on superuser instead, but try http://shareme.com/details/virtual-webcamera-splitter.html or http://multiply1cam.info/

Comment: Yes I need to access it in two different programs, will take a look,thanks!